# AngularJS - UI-Router with wizard

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ui-router to setup my routes like below:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'path/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    })
    .state('basket', {
        url: "/basket",
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'path/basket.html',
                controller: 'BasketController'
            },
            'address@basket': {
                templateUrl: 'path/address.html',
                controller: 'AddressController'
            },
            'confirmation@basket': {
                templateUrl: 'path/confirmation.html',
                controller: 'ConfirmationController'
            },
            'payment@basket': {
                templateUrl: 'path/payment.html',
                controller: 'PaymentController'
            }
        }
    });
```

In my `basket.html` I'm using `mgo-angular-wizard` to create a "step bar".

```
<wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()">

<wz-step title="Address">
    <div ui-view="address"></div>
</wz-step>

<wz-step title="Confirmation">
    <div ui-view="confirmation"></div>
</wz-step>

<wz-step title="Payment">
    <div ui-view="payment"></div>
</wz-step>
```

So far it's working fine. But I need to create buttons that will also navigate between those pages. For example: Address page needs a button which is going to call Confirmation page.
I saw some pages in the web which were using `ui-sref="$state.go('basket.address')"` but, since I'm not using this structure (with dot), I don't know how to do it (using `confirmation@basket` isn't working).

I'm new to Angular and learning on the flow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need anything else except Ui.Router, because is angular you can navigate between states in a non-stateless way (saving something in services for example).

A good thing could be having nested states...

steps:

1. Create the parent abstract state: **Basket** that allows child states to inherit views, resolves, url-fragments.
2. Create child states: **address; confirmation; payment**

```js
angular
  .module('checkout', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    
    var basket = {
      name: 'basket',
      url: '/basket/',
      abstract: true,
      views: {
        "main": {
          template: "<h1>Bye</h1>",
          controller: function() { alert('bye'); }
        },
        "sidebar": {
          template: "<ul><li>LINK</li></ul>",
          controller: function() { console.log('sidebar view'); }
        }
      }
    };
    
    var address = {
      name: 'basket.address',
      url: ''
    };
  
    var confirmation = {
      name: 'basket.confirmation',
      url: 'confirmation/',
      views: {
        "main@": {
          template: "<h1>ss</h1>",
          controller: function() { alert('ss'); }
        }
      }
    };
      
  
    var payment = {
      name: 'basket.payment',
      url: 'payment/',
      views: {
        "main@": {
          template: "<h1>zz</h1>",
          controller: function() { alert('zz'); }
        }
      }
    };    
  
    $stateProvider
      .state(basket)
      .state(address)
      .state(confirmation)
      .state(payment)
    ;
  })
;
```

```html
<section ui-view="main"></section>
<aside ui-view="sidebar"></aside>

<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="basket.address">Address</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="basket.confirmation">Confirmation</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref="basket.payment">Payment</a></li>

</ul>
```

3. Create a service via **angular.module('checkout').value** that stores all checkout progresses.

---

By the way, if you need to keep all views and states in one you probably need this Ui.Router.extra called **[STICKY STATES](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky)**, the link provides many examples...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Using `<div ui-view="basket"></div>` doesn't work (which should open basket.address). Can't I set controllers and templateUrls?